Calculate the solution of the problem
Calculate the minimum and maximum no of element comparisons involved in 2 way merge sort,
I. assuming n =2^k , (k > 0)
II. n is not a power of 2
I am trying to figure out in the case of 2^k the the min comparison for pass one is n/2*1 and pass 2 : n/4 *2 , that's how we can calculate the nth term
And for max it's pass 1 : n/2*(1+1-1) and pass 2 : n/4*(2+2-1)
This is questions are from cormen book which is heaven for software engineers

stackoverflow.com may be more helpful to you
